# Getting 'node_contextify' error with `rails s` - and 'bad request error' from npm-pipeline-rails when running `npm audit`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, gulp

Using npm-pipeline-rails gem, I try to run rails in order to compile assets via Gulp:

```
$ rails s
> gulp watch
gulp[1624]: ../src/node_contextify.cc:635:static void node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
```

Everyone says to simply `rm -rf node_modules/`, `rm package-lock.json`, `npm i`, `npm audit fix`, but I get this:

```
$ npm audit fix
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - POST https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
  "name": "gulp-app",
  "description": "Description",
  "author": "Your Name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp watch",
    "build": "gulp build"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "breakpoint-sass": "^2.7.0",
    "compass-mixins": "",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cli": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-run": "^1.7.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "susy": "^2.2.14"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be a symptom of not having a version declared in package.json

This fixes it for me:
`"compass-mixins": "^0.12.6",` in place of `"compass-mixins": "",`

Then you can simply `rm -rf node_modules/`, `rm package-lock.json`, `npm i`, `npm audit fix`... and then try `rails s` again.